# How to make an image fill a container/sidebar?

Tags: html, image, margin, padding, sidebar

My sidebar is 130px in width. I had this: `<div style="min-height: 700px;">&nbsp;</div>` and it was displaying an outline of the block where the sidebar is, just to point out where the sidebar will be.

I want to add an image that is 130x350px to basically fill in the space of the sidebar and shorten it. I tried this:

```
<div style="min-height: 350px;"><img alt="" src="imageuploads/smallsidebarimage.png" />&nbsp;</div>
```

the image was in the middle but much smaller with a lot of padding maybe 20px around on each side.

Then I tried this and the image is displaying the right size now, but it's placed about 10px to the right and 10px lower over the left edge of my sidebar.

```
<div style="min-height: 350px; min-width: 130px; width: 100%;"><img class="pull-left" alt="" src="imageuploads/smallsidebarimage.png" />&nbsp;</div>
```

How can I make my image fill the sidebar space? I don't want the outline it's showing now either...

Comment: Can you make a fiddle (http://fiddle.jshell.net/) for this?

Comment: Have you tried `img { display: block; width: 100%; }` in your stylesheet/inline-styles?